# Is there a Finder shortcut in Mac like the "Windows-e" shortcut to bring up Windows Explorer?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

In Windows, no matter what application you're in, <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> will bring up a Windows Explorer window.

Is there a similar shortcut in Mac? Currently I have to <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> until Finder is selected, then press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> for a new window.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no shortcut integrated into the OS. However, there are workarounds:

1. <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> opens a Spotlight window, from which you can navigate to where you wish to go as in Finder. (It is essentially a Finder window, just opened to Spotlight)
2. Use a shortcuts manager such as [Quicksilver](http://www.blacktree.com/) or [Spark](http://www.shadowlab.org/Software/spark.php) to create a custom shortcut.

Comment: Nice! I like the Spotlight window. It's good enough. Thanks!

Comment: The problem with OPTION + COMMAND + SPACE is that each time you use it, a new finder window seems to get created. This is annoying!

Comment: @Phani yes, it is annoying. So open finder with OPTION + COMMAND + SPACE and then hit COMMAND + W and it brings the previously open finder to screen

Comment: @Phani Windows + e also opens a new Explorer window in Windows. So, OPTION + COMMAND + SPACE **is** equivalent of Windows + e

Comment: Since I worked on both - windows and mac, I look forward to similar shortcuts. So I changed the `OPTION + COMMAND + SPACE` to `COMMAND + E` as I am too used to `WIN + E`.

Answer (score 15):

There is a more generic way, although not straightforward.

1. *Open* **Automator**
2. *Create* a **new service**
3. Close to the upper-left corner of the automator window, there is a **button labelled "Variables"**: *push it*
4. In the **second column** there is a **variable named "Path"**: *double-click it*
5. A **blue bubble labelled "Path"** appears in a list at the bottom right of the automator window: *double-click it*
6. **In the pop-up**, *change the directory*: *Select the directory* that will be the initial one shown by your Finder, then *click* **"Done"**.
7. *Drag* the **bubble "Path"** to the empty grey area at the right of the window and *drop it*: an item named "Get Value of Variable" appears as first step of the workflow
8. *Click* on the **button "Actions"** next to the button "Variables" (See step 3)
9. In the first column, *select* **"Files or folders"**
10. In the second column *double-click* **"Open Finder Items"**: an item named "Open Finder Items" appears as second step of the workflow
11. *Make sure* you read "Service receives **no input** in **any application**" above the workflow diagram
12. *Save* the service, using **menu File/Save**. *Type in* the name **"Openfinder"**, then click "Save"
13. Now *open the **System Preferences***
14. *Select* **Keyboard, then Keyboard and shortcuts**
15. In the left column, *highlight* **Services**
16. In the right column, *find* the name **"Openfinder"** in the "General" section and *select it*
17. *Click* the button **"Add shortcut"** next to the name **"Openfinder"**
18. *Type* the **shortcut of your choice** (but conflicts with existing shortcuts do not seem to be notified by te system)

Sorry for the number of steps. I wish it were simpler.

You can use this method to create any kind of shortcut!

Comment: your solution is THE most complex, but it offers an important overview on a fundamental feature of OSX.
Thanks for sharing a so long and detailed step-by-step instructions list, it really helped me.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Now, the only trouble is to choose a shortcut key that doesn't clash with other applications.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you! I used it to open different 'specific' folders quickly.

Answer (score 7):

Thought I share this perfect solution with you guys, which I cannot believe I haven't find anywhere on web.

Go to -> System Preferences -> Keyboard

Scroll to -> Spotlight

Mark "Show Spotlight Window", and put your desired shortcut

I use Control-E which is easiest in my opinion to press from Mac keyboard.

It acts even better than Windows Explorer, when you customize the sidebar on Finder Window for your most accessed Folders (I suggest hiding the color code balls also). In Finder, make sure you have "View -> Show Toolbar and Show Sidebar" enabled.

You are welcome.

Comment: Thank you!!  Trying to adjust to OSX the lack of the Win+E equivalent was killing me.  For something that mimicked the Windows setup the closest, I used the "command" key.  Tip for anyone coming in, it isn't obvious how to change the value.  You have to click on the existing keyboard shortcut, then you can enter a new one.  Also, in OSX Yosemite, it is under Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Spotlight

Comment: I think they changed the location. It's now easier to go from `System Preferences > Spotlight > Keyboard Shortcuts...`.

Answer (score 5):

yes there is a way; option(alt), command, space.

Comment: This needs to be actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug on 10.7 and 10.8 where the shortcuts for Automator services don't always work until you hover over the services menu from the menu bar. There's also a small delay before services are run, and they don't work in applications that don't have a menu bar or a [services menu](https://superuser.com/questions/432969/services-keyboard-shortcuts-dont-work-for-some-mac-apps).

It's probably better to just rely on third party applications, like [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com), [Apptivate](http://www.apptivateapp.com), [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net), or [QuickSilver](http://qsapp.com).

Comment: +1 for a list of cool applications. I heavily use BetterTouchTool and I love it!

Answer (score 1):

Since Automator has changed since 2013, I post an updated version of @sdive's solution. To create a service using Automator on Mac OS Catalina (find a screenshot of the service below):

1. Open Automator
2. Create a **New Document** > **Quick Action**
3. Select **"Workflow receives `no input` in `any application`"** (and optionally choose an Image to your liking)
4. Click **Library** on the top left (below the close button, if it is not already active)
5. Click **Variables > Locations**
6. Drag the **Path** action to your workflow window
7. At the bottom, double click the variable and **set path to the folder you want to open**
8. In the Library, navgiate to **Actions > Files & Folders**
9. Drag **Open Finder Items** to your workflow (leave the action unchanged)
10. Click **Run** (at the top right), the path you set in step 7 should be opened in finder.
11. **Save** your action, e.g. as "Open MyFolder"
12. With Automator as your active window, next to your apple icon click: **Automator > Services > Service Preferences** (or go to *Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services* via System Preferences)
13. **Find your action in the General Section** at the bottom of the Services list
14. Assign a shortcut (e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>)

[image: Screenshot of the final service]

Answer (score 1):

If you want a new Finder window if no other is open, but to come back to the already opened Finder window if there's already one that you don't see, (as Windows + E works) the most straight forward way, at least in **Big Sur** and **Monterey**, is pressing `⌘`+ `Space`+ `F` together and then `Enter`.

`⌘` + `Space`+ `F` opens the Finder. The `Enter` is needed in one of the versions at least.

If it is the first time you look for the Finder in Spotlight, you might need to select it first after pressing `f` but you won't need that next time.

In **Ventura** you only need to press `⌘` + `F` while on the desktop. It seems it always opens a new Finder.

Answer (score 0):

Since System Settings changed since @Gizmoriderful Ye's answer, heres the new path through the system settings:

1. Go to "system Settings" -> "Keyboard"
2. Select the button "Keyboard Shortcuts" which opens a sub-window
3. Select "Spotlight" in the sidebar
4. double tap on the current shortcut, usally: option + command + Space

now you can hit the shortcut you wish to have, like: command + E

written for macOS 13.4.1