# Services keyboard shortcuts don't work for some mac apps

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion

I am using this answer [Starting application with custom keyboard shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/245711/starting-application-with-custom-keyboard-shortcut) and it works great on most mac apps.

However some apps, like Git Tower and HipChat client, don't have the "Services" menu item so the keyboard shortcuts don't work when they have focus.

Any way around it?

Comment: The only way around it I know of, is to use a third-party utility, like the answer suggests. Even if an app has the **Services** menu available, you always have to reveal it first by clicking on the menu bar, to circumvent the mentioned bug. If you don't need all the horsepower of apps like LaunchBar, Alfred or Quicksilver, you can try [Aptivate](http://www.apptivateapp.com/).